# Script# - type or namespace name 'ScriptAssemblyAttribute' could not be found

Tags: c#, dynamics-365, script#

I have a template project that uses Script# (downloaded from here: https://github.com/scottdurow/SparkleXrm). I've built and deployed this many times so not sure if this is an environmental issue or a version issue. I stripped the solution right down to 2 projects - ClientUi (which references Script#) and a CRMPackage where my HTML page is, but when I build I get the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'ScriptAssemblyAttribute' could not be found
```

...and I can't get rid of it. I'm on VS 2017, Windows 10, Project version is .net 4.0 (have tried changing it to 4.5, same problem).

Have tried reapplying Script# via NuGet, but it's just not happy with me and keeps throwing the error. Have tried clearing VS cache, cleaning the build and restarting visual studio, standing on my head, drinking wine, nothing seems to work. In fact I think the wine made it worse.

Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future people hitting this, it's a Visual Studio version issue. Preview 2 broke ScriptSharp compilation. It's something to do with a mismatch in mscorlib versions.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/138986/1550-preview-2-breaks-scriptsharp-compilation.html

As per the above link, the fix is setting the following flag in the MSBuild project file:

```
<DisableHandlePackageFileConflicts>true</DisableHandlePackageFileConflicts>
```